# Select one record from left table, but multiple from right table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, where I want to select all the data where it matches on identifier, however I want to replace the repeated data collected from table A to NULL. My current result is shown in the Current Table (refer to attached image). I want results displayed as shown in New Table.

My Current SQL is:

```
SELECT                   
a.name, a.desc, b.seq    
from table_a a, table_b b
where a.name = b.name
```

I believe I can possibly do this by using CASE:

```
CASE 
WHEN
b.seq = 1 THEN a.name, a.desc ELSE a.name IS NULL, a.desc IS NULL
END
```

But I'm not having any luck. Any help please?

Thank you!

[image: Table example]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your sample results don't match your query, which makes the query hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CASE` clause:

```
select
  case when b.seq = 1 then a.name end,
  case when b.seq = 1 then a.desc end,
  b.seq
from table_a a
join table_b b on a.name = b.name
```